# How to query a mongo field disregarding capital letters and symbols

Tags: arrays, regex, mongodb

I have a mongo field that contains an array of genres for the specific doc such as "Shooter" and "Action & Adventure" or "Roleplaying". I am trying to do searching functionality over these fields where the user passes a comma separated list in a query parameter which a convert to an array to pass to the server to determine the correct document to return. similar to below.. with url www.example.com?generes=test,test1,test3 which gives the array

```
['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

The problem comes on the server when trying to form the correct mongo query for the document. As I said, the docs in the db have generes with many url unsafe characters along with capital letters. How would I form a mongo query that would return return docs with the genre "Shooter" or "Action & Adventure" when given an array of values such as `["shooter", "actionandadventure"]`
I have tried a couple regular expressions such as [AZaz] but nothing that fits my exact needs. Any help is much appreciated:)

Comment: use array of regex `collection.find({"generes": { "$in": [ /shooter/i, /action/i, /adventure/i ] } })`

Comment: Your query working properly for any case.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this. Thanks!